# Salesforce chatbot not rendering SLDS CSS StyleSheet on Android Webview, what is the wrong with Salesforce

Tags: android, einstein-chatbot, pre-chat

I am developing Salesforce chatbot in Android using JavaScript file. I am using Webview to load the content and it shows **Chat with an Expert** button.

When I clicking on this button prechat page coming up, this page is kind of simple html, there is **no CSS applied**.
How can I get CSS Styles render on my Webview ?
This is how my page looking like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the BaseChatMessage. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightningsnapin-base-chat-message) is the reference

More Detail is given [here](https://quip.com/WM7AA3tXRsaf).

Download the SLDS CSS. Then upload it to the Static Resources.
Then in the LWC component which extends the BaseChatMessage, just include this in ConnectedCallBack.

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import SLDS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SLDS';

connectedCallback() 
{
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this,SLDS)
    ]);
}
```